# Plotting ROC curves in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, deep-learning

I have trained an eight classes classifier deep learning model. The model performs good on 10 folds, with an average of 0.91 f1 score. I tried to generate ROC curve and I got this[image]

I was expecting an exponential curve but I got this one like straight lines. Is there anything wrong with the curve shape produced by my model or even this shape is acceptable?

Comment: I'd be suspicious of the class 7 AUC. Without seeing some train and test data, and some code, it's kind of hard to say more. Or maybe I don't have enough experience to say more :)

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, I think sklearn is your friend!!

```
print(__doc__)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from scipy import interp

# Import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Binarize the output
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = y.shape[1]

# Add noisy features to make the problem harder
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]

# shuffle and split training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.5,
                                                    random_state=0)

# Learn to predict each class against the other
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
                                 random_state=random_state))
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)

# Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

# Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])

plt.figure()
lw = 2
plt.plot(fpr[2], tpr[2], color='darkorange',
         lw=lw, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc[2])
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=lw, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic example')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()


# Compute macro-average ROC curve and ROC area

# First aggregate all false positive rates
all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr[i] for i in range(n_classes)]))

# Then interpolate all ROC curves at this points
mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
for i in range(n_classes):
    mean_tpr += interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])

# Finally average it and compute AUC
mean_tpr /= n_classes

fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr
roc_auc["macro"] = auc(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"])

# Plot all ROC curves
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"],
         label='micro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})'
               ''.format(roc_auc["micro"]),
         color='deeppink', linestyle=':', linewidth=4)

plt.plot(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"],
         label='macro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})'
               ''.format(roc_auc["macro"]),
         color='navy', linestyle=':', linewidth=4)

colors = cycle(['aqua', 'darkorange', 'cornflowerblue'])
for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), colors):
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], color=color, lw=lw,
             label='ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
             ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', lw=lw)
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Some extension of Receiver operating characteristic to multi-class')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you plotted correctly, but seems like your model is too 'simple' such curves are possible when your model produce near ideal performance. You'll get straight lines and AUC = 1 when your model is able to separate two classes perfectly (ROC of class 7 in your case).
Maybe add more features and broaden your model in case you left out some intentionally.